# Can we automate an application which runs on mobile browser(Not mobile app) using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: mobile, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

There is an application which users access on Samsung NOTE devices. Requirement is to automate the regression suite on mobile(Samsung NOTE). This application works on PC also, and I have managed to automate using selenium on PC successfully.

Could anyone help me know, if we can use selenium to automate the mobile version of it? I mean can my selenium script automate the mobile browser.

If we can't achieve, what automation tool can I use to automate the same?

Comment: To make it clear: There is a web app that users use mostly on Samsung NOTE phones, however it's an web app. Do you need to automate tests using its build-in browser or any browsers running on this phone will do?

Comment: @Mikhail - The browser which users use in the Samsung NOTE device is Google Chrome. Requirement is to automate tests on Chrome. I am not sure if Chrome is the built-in browser for NOTE device.

Comment: Of course you can. Google Appium..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the provided comment you have 2 approaches you may take at this point:

1. Using Chrome options and mobile emulation params in `WebDriver` as `DesiredCapabilities` refer to this page for more details: 
   https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/mobile-emulation - you can do the same from your own browser in dev tools. This should be enough for 90% of cases, however if you want to make sure that env you're running your tests is as close to real users as possible see 2.
2. Using special tools that create specific instances of WebDriver, like [Selendroid](http://selendroid.io/) or [Appium](http://appium.io/) - in this case you may either run your tests on emulated device(by creating instances from Android SDK or from Xcode) or you even have ability to connect real devices and execute your tests on them